# Pixels retrieved from Viewer Node within Blender are darker than the actually rendered image... Why?

Tags: python, blender, bpy

I am trying to create a pipeline in which I first render an image using the blender python API (I am using Blender 2.90) and then perform some image processing in python. I want to fetch the image directly from blender without first writing the rendered image to disk and then loading it again. I ran the following code within the blender GUI to do so:

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
import PIL.Image as Image 
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte 

resolution_x = 512
resolution_y = 512

# render settings
scene = bpy.context.scene
scene.render.engine = 'BLENDER_EEVEE'
scene.render.resolution_x = resolution_x
scene.render.resolution_y = resolution_y
scene.render.image_settings.file_format = 'PNG'
scene.render.filepath = "path/to/good_image.png"

# create Viewer Layer in Compositor
scene.use_nodes = True
tree = scene.node_tree 
nodes = tree.nodes
links = tree.links

for node in nodes:
    nodes.remove(node)

render_layer_node = nodes.new('CompositorNodeRLayers')
viewer_node = nodes.new('CompositorNodeViewer')

links.new(viewer_node.inputs[0], render_layer_node.outputs[0])

# render scene and get pixels from Viewer Node
bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True) 
pixels = bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].pixels

# do some processing and save
img = np.flip(img_as_ubyte(np.array(pixels[:]).reshape((resolution_y, resolution_x, 4))), axis=0)
Image.fromarray(img).save("path/to/bad_image.png")
```

Problem: The image I get from the Viewer Node is much darker ([bad image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vImGQ.png)) than the image saved in the conventional way ([good image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuHrr.png)). Does anyone have an idea why this happens and how to fix it? Does blender maybe treat pixel values differently than I expect?

Some additional information:
Before conversion to uint8, the values of the alpha channel within the dark image are 1.0 (as they actually should be). Background values in the dark image are not 0.0 or negative (as one might guess from appearance), but 0.05...

What I tried:
I thought that pixels might be scaled within range -1 to 1, so I rescaled the pixels to range 0 to 1 before transforming to uint8... Did not lead to the correct image either :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the image that you get from the `Viewer Node` is the one "straight from compositing" before color management takes place. You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/color_management.html): this image is still in the linear space.

Your `good_image.png` on the other hand is obtained after transformation into the "Display Space" (see diagram in the doc). Hence it was transformed into a log-space, maybe gamma-corrected, etc.

Finally, you can get an image that is close to (but slightly different though) to the good image from the viewer node by calling `bpy.data.images['Viewer Node'].save_render(filepath)` instead, but there is no way to directly extract the color-managed version without rendering to a file first. You can probably do it yourself by adding `PyOpenColorIO` to your script and applying the color management from this module.